# Error Getting Record "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

In the following code, I am trying to get a profile for the user that is currently logged in.

```
Dim userProfile = db1.UserProfiles.Where(Function(p) p.UserId = Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey).Single
```

The error is "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object CompareObjectEqual(System.Object, System.Object, Boolean)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Does anyone know what's wrong with this, or is there a better way... And, how can I make this more secure; i.e. add a condition if no record is found?

I am using VB ASP.NET MVC 3.

Thank you.

Edit:

Here's my new code:

```
        Dim db1 As UserProfileDbContext = New UserProfileDbContext
        Dim user = Membership.GetUser()
        Dim key As Guid = user.ProviderUserKey
        Dim finalKey = key.ToString
        Dim userProfile = db1.UserProfiles.Where(Function(p) p.UserId = finalKey).Single
        Dim companyId = userProfile.CompanyId
```

Comment: What is the type of the `UserId` property?

Comment: UserId is a string from the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L2E is trying to render your lamba expression `(p) p.UserId = Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey` in to an SQL Expression which it can use to hit the database.

However, `Membership.GetUser()` is a .NET method. L2E is complaining that it doesn't know how to render this method in to SQL syntax.

Try this instead:

```
Dim user = Membership.GetUser()
Dim userProfile = db1.UserProfiles.Where(Function(p) p.UserId = user.ProviderUserKey).Single
```

**edit**: MembershipUser.ProviderUserKey is a CLR `Object`. SQL can't compare two objects, so you'll need to strong type it before running the expression. For example, if your user key is a `String`:

```
Dim user = Membership.GetUser()
Dim key as String= user.ProviderUserKey
Dim userProfile = db1.UserProfiles.Where(Function(p) p.UserId = key).Single
```

This should work better because a simple equality expression `=` is understood by L2E and can be rendered in to an equivilent SQL expression, something like:

`SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE UserId = @Argument`, where the @Argument is supplied by entity framework.

Also as an aside, L2E will group chained calls until the end, so an expression like:

`db1.UserProfiles.Skip(10).Take(30).Where(Function(p) p.UserId = Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey)`

... would still fail, because L2E will combine the `Skip` `Take` and `Where` components in to a single SQL expression. You can force L2E to hit the server by calling `ToArray` `ToList` or `ToDictionary`. That expression could be made valid by changing it to:

`db1.UserProfiles.Skip(10).Take(30).ToArray().Where(Function(p) p.UserId = Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey)`

The `ToArray` forces the execution of the SQL statement, giving you a .NET Array which *does* support complex lambas.

Comment: Thanks that took care of that error but I get a new one that says, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  Any idea on that one or should I open a new question?

Comment: Can you step through the debugger and see if Membership.GetUser is returning null? null.ProviderUserKey will surely cause a problem. Also, `.Single()` is programmed to throw an exception if the resultset is empty- in other words, if it fails to find a profile.

Comment: Sorry to waste your time.  I realized I got logged out which would make the current user null.  However, when logging in and running the code, I still get this error, "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object CompareObjectEqual(System.Object, System.Object, Boolean)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: That's because MembershipUser.ProviderUserKey is an object. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I tried the latest code but it didn't work, so I finally tried converting the guid into a string to be compared with the other string from the database, but it gives me an error "The 'IsCompanyOwner' property on 'UserProfile' could not be set to a 'String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Boolean'."  I updated my question with my current code.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to data bind a `Boolean` column in the SQL table to a `String` value in your CLR entity. If your `UserProfile` entity is custom-defined, make sure that `IsCompanyOwner` is a Boolean.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14765/discussion-between-kivin-and-user1477388)